# Ionic 4 Tabs styling

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to give the tabs in a ionic 4 app a gradient background.
I am also trying to set a different color (Gradient) background for each page.
Controlling the style for the tabs in the scss for each page.

The desired affect is as below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<shadow-root>` which indicates that the browser you're using supports Shadow DOM technique so you can access its elements by only their variables,So try the following

```
ion-toolbar {
  --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #... 0%, #... 100%) !important;
}

ion-tab-bar {
  --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #... 0%, #... 100%) !important;
}
```

If it doesn't work just please detect father -i call it- or its wrapper and put it in advance of it,In another word

```
wrapper ion-tab-bar {
--ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #... 0%, #... 100%) !important;
}
```

wrapper refers to the element that wrapping `ion-tab-bar`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CSS gradient to the toolbar (top) and tabbar (bottom):

```
ion-toolbar{
  --background: linear-gradient(to right, #color1 0%, #color2 100%);
}

ion-tab-bar{
  --background: linear-gradient(to right, #color1 0%, #color2 100%);
}
```

In case you want to set the gradient for the whole app, place the CSS inside theme > variable.scss

Docs

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-bar

Comment: Do I remove the color attribute from the tab bar as I have already tried this and it had no affect.

Comment: @StantonRoux you should fill in your own hex color codes for color1 and color2. Like from green to blue: linear-gradient(to right, #00FF00 0%, #0000FF 100%)

Comment: Sorry this is not working. I am using this code and has no affect on the tab-bar Sorry this is not working.  This is the code used on the page ion-tab-bar{
  --background: linear-gradient(to right, #ed1e78 0%, #f79220 100%) !important;
} its having no affecr

Comment: @StantonRoux Is it working on the toolbar? Where do you place the code? I've placed the code in theme > variables.scss and the toolbar / tabbar where filled with the gradient.

Comment: toolbar is working perfectly, tab-bar not working think it has something to do with the shadow-root thing.  When I add it to the variables file it ads cradients to each tab not the background. Its also cannot be overwritten by the pages scss file