# Ionic 5 ion-tab-bar gradient background

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Hello everyone I want to set the ion-tab-bar background to gradient like the toolbar in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkAl.png).

What I have tried. (sets the toolbar as expected but doesn't work as intended for the tab-bar)

```
--ion-toolbar-background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 149, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(241, 90, 41, 1) 100%);
--ion-toolbar-color: var(--ion-color-light);

--ion-tab-bar-background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 149, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(241, 90, 41, 1) 100%);
--ion-tab-bar-color: var(--ion-color-light);
```

Checking [Ionic 4 Tabs styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800871/ionic-4-tabs-styling) I tried the following but still same result.

```
ion-tab-bar {
  --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 149, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(241, 90, 41, 1) 100%) !important;
}
```

```
ion-tabs ion-tab-bar {
  --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 149, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(241, 90, 41, 1) 100%) !important;
}
```

All help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 4 Tabs styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800871/ionic-4-tabs-styling)

Comment: @E.Maggini I tried it but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it using

```
ion-tab-bar {
--background: transparent;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 149, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(241, 90, 41, 1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: its not working on ionic 6

Comment: @sumanta.k the title states ionic 5, i'm not up to date on this matter.